# How can I make actions union type from action creator object?

Tags: typescript

I want to create actions union type from action creator object.

expect behavior

```
type SomeActionCreator = {
    hoge: () => {type: 'hoge'}
    foo: () => {type: 'foo'}
    baz: {
        baz1: () => {type: 'baz1'}
        baz2: () => {type: 'baz2'}
    }
}

type SomAction = MakeActions<SomeActionCreator>
// SomeAction: {type: 'hoge'} | {type: 'foo'} | {type: 'baz1'} | {type: 'baz2'}
```

My implementation.

```
type ActionCreator = (...args: never[]) => {type: string}
type ActionCreatorObj = {
    [name: string]: ActionCreator | ActionCreatorObj
}
type MakeActions<T extends ActionCreatorObj> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends ActionCreator ? ReturnType<T[K]> : MakeActions<T[K]>
}[keyof T]

type SomeActionCreator = {
    hoge: () => {type: 'hoge'}
    foo: () => {type: 'foo'}
    baz: {
        baz1: () => {type: 'baz1'}
        baz2: () => {type: 'baz2'}
    }
}
type SomAction = MakeActions<SomeActionCreator>
```

But I encountered compile error at `MakeActions<T[K]>` as follows.

```
Type 'T[K]' does not satisfy the constraint 'ActionCreatorObj'.
  Type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to type 'ActionCreatorObj'.
    Type 'T[string] | T[number] | T[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'ActionCreatorObj'.
      Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'ActionCreatorObj'.
        Type 'ActionCreator | ActionCreatorObj' is not assignable to type 'ActionCreatorObj'.
          Type 'ActionCreator' is not assignable to type 'ActionCreatorObj'.
            Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'ActionCreator'.(2344)
```

I appreciate your support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You additionally have to check if `T[K] extends ActionCreatorObj`. `T[K]` could be of any type in your else `:` because at that point we only know that `T[K]` does not extend `ActionCreator` and we can only pass `T[K]` as ageneric argument to the recursive `MakeActions` type if it is of type `ActionCreatorObj`.

```
type SomeActionCreator = {
  hoge: () => { type: "hoge" };
  foo: () => { type: "foo" };
  baz: {
    baz1: () => { type: "baz1" };
    baz2: () => { type: "baz2" };
  };
};

type ActionCreator = () => { type: string };
type ActionCreatorObj = {
  [name: string]: ActionCreator | ActionCreatorObj;
};
type MakeActions<T extends ActionCreatorObj> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends ActionCreator
    ? ReturnType<T[K]>
    : T[K] extends ActionCreatorObj
    ? MakeActions<T[K]>
    : never;
}[keyof T];

type SomeAction = MakeActions<SomeActionCreator>;
const someAction: SomeAction = { type: "baz2" };
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgQQMbAJZwHYGEBOEAhsHPlALxQDeAUFFABZwDmEAXFABQCUlAfDSihInAETM2YqAF8A3PSgAzOHE68BQkRyhiVcafMUAjIgC9OdBg1NmAjOr4VB1YeB1jbdwwutRbAEyOmq7a4oE+ikZGtNpQaJg4BMSk5FQazlrunADOwPgY2CyyCnEJWHiEJGQA8sYAVpQ0igDa2ERIufmFLAC6nOVJValQAD7x6BXJ1fh19QpGcQCyRADWKJM4OQA8ACpQEAAewBDYACY5E4mVKbUNglRWUC0A0lCFUOsgcEpQu-1-V69A7HU4XK5TYZkRQMAD8UAAShBgABXfDYXbuPZA-gwqCcXZAkEnc6XQY3GZzPHwlbrck7QkvXq4vycbAQABuEHwCxaXx+f16Cli7lgiA21yatIlFR28CQ5OmqX4ClQW2AUBy4vJnHlMpwTVC2V0ERKtCAA)